# Precompiling rails assets caused undefined method directory? for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets, precompile

I am trying to precompile assets in my rails app, and getting this

```
$ ber assets:precompile --trace
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `directory?' for nil:NilClass
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprock
ets/base.rb:307:in `block in each_entry'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprock
ets/base.rb:303:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprock
ets/base.rb:303:in `each_entry'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprock
ets/base.rb:322:in `block in each_file'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprock
ets/base.rb:321:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprock
ets/base.rb:321:in `each_file'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprock
ets/base.rb:335:in `each_logical_path'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprock
ets/manifest.rb:115:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprock
ets/manifest.rb:115:in `to_a'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprock
ets/manifest.rb:115:in `compile'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/s
prockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/rake/s
procketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/s
prockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:240:in `call'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:240:in `block in execute'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:235:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:235:in `execute'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.r
b:165:in `invoke'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:100:in `top_level'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:78:in `block in run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/applic
ation.rb:75:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in
`<top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error when I referenced a directory in my `application.js.erb` that did not exist anymore. It can also be a broken softlink that might cause this error but I see you are on Windows so that can be excluded almost a 100%.

Check your asset files for typing errors in situations you reference other files or for directories that existed but have been removed.

Comment: will give to you for attemptign, but i think there was something wrong with the windows setup, i cloned to a mac and it worked.